# Sharepoint list column shows no result on "Find an item"

Tags: splistitem, splist

I have a custom SP List that has a few columns consist of Full Name, extension, Job title, Department and so on. When I search using the list "Find an item" box on department there are results produced but I search based on Full Name the results returned are empty. I look up through managed properties and found property FullNameOWSTEXT is greyed out so I changed it and set the properties to be query, refined, safe, searchable and map it to ows_fullname and ows_q_TEXT_FullName. I waited for the crawl to finish and try to search full name again but still, no result was produced.

The content approval settings have been set to "No" as well.

Basically, I've tried everything that I could find in google.

Do I need to create a new property for Full Name and link it back to my site column or is there other settings that I missed?

Thank you.